# ORA-00990 error while trying to grant priviliges: Why is that?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, permissions

After creating a user named `suhail` I am trying to grant that user some privileges. But I am getting an error saying *missing or invalid privilege* . Why is that ?

```
C:\Windows\system32>SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Mar 5 08:11:35 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
SQL> CREATE USER suhail IDENTIFIED BY InnocentDesire02;
User created.
SQL> GRANT CREATE TABLE,ALTER TABLE,INSERT TABLE,SELECT TABLE,DELETE TABLE,DROP 
VIEW,CREATE ROLE,CREATE SESSION,ALTER SESSION TO suhail;

GRANT CREATE TABLE,ALTER TABLE,INSERT TABLE,SELECT TABLE,DELETE TABLE,DROP VIEW,CREATE   
ROLE,CREATE SESSION,ALTER SESSION TO suhail

               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list of privileges contains a number that don't exist.  There is no `ALTER TABLE` privilege.  Nor is there a `SELECT TABLE` or `DELETE TABLE` or `DROP VIEW` privilege.  You can grant a user `SELECT` access on individual tables that are owned by other users.